# retrieve picklist values for OmniProcess custom object

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I need to retrieve the Picklist values/metadata for the OmniProcess standard object, I've checked this [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) from the official Salesforce documentation but I didn't find any information. Also when I look for the OmniProcess standard object, it only says "For Internal use Only".

package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>OmniProcess.SubType</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</type>
```

Comment: OmniProcess is a specialized standard object within Salesforce, designed to power [OmniStudio](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_omnistudio_sobject_descriptions.htm&type=5) features. Due to its internal role, Salesforce limits direct access to its metadata and picklist values. Can you describe the general outcome you're hoping to achieve with the object?